# Self-referencing in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, self-reference, pscustomobject

I would like to do some "self-referencing"(?) in PowerShell v3.

In a remote script I do:

```bsh
New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{MyProperty="test"}
```

But I don't know how to access this Property inside this remote script.
This Property exist because in my local script I'm able to access it by

```bsh
$MyScriptBlock.MyProperty
```

Inside my `$MyScriptBlock`-

In C# I could write

```cs
this.MyProperty="MyInfo"
```

In VB I could write

```vb
Me.MyProperty="MyInfo"
```

In HTA I could write

```vb
document.MyProperty="MyInfo"
```

In some other

```
self.MyProperty="MyInfo"
```

So, how to do in PowerShell v3 ?

How to do Self-referencing in PowerShell ? (not only for this script)

Today, I can't pipe it (script a bit complex with 700 lines)
I have to reuse this variable.

To explain what this script do :

I have a remote script on a server, called with

```
$MyRemoteScript = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $MyRemoteScriptBlock
```

Inside the remote script I do

```
New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{MyProperty= $False}
```

In remote script, sometime, I would like to change MyProperty

Later, in host script, I read MyProperty by

```
$Success = $MyRemoteScript.MyProperty
```

Comment: In PowerShell, If you just do `new-object pscustomobject -Property @{MyProperty="test"}` and do not assign it to a variable it will be intermediately put into the pipeline. In other words, if you would like to reuse the object, you will need to assign it to a variable: `$me = new-object pscustomobject -Property @{MyProperty="test"}`

Comment: Assign the object to a variable inside the scriptblock. Output that variable at the end of the scriptblock. Make sure you're not generating any other output on the success output stream.